install docker bash script doesn't work when used as Custom Data for Azure VM
I use this script to install docker on my Azure VM, OS Debian Bullseye 11:
echo "** Updating package lists..."
sudo apt update

echo "** Installing dependencies..."
sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg software-properties-common

echo "** Adding Docker GPG key..."
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "** Adding Docker repository..."
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable" 

echo "** Updating package lists again..."
sudo apt update

echo "** Installing Docker..."
sudo apt install -y docker-ce

echo "** Docker installation complete!"

If I run this script manually (1 line at a time) it works, however when I use it as Custom Data so it would execute on VM initialization, it gives errors, here's the var/logs/cloud-init-output.log:
    ** Updating package lists...

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 700 (apt-get)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
** Installing dependencies...

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package gnupg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnupg' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
** Adding Docker GPG key...
E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
(23) Failed writing body
** Adding Docker repository...
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
** Updating package lists again...

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 700 (apt-get)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
** Installing Docker...

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce
** Docker installation complete!


Pasted your log there twice my friend. Could you edit and put your script in? Also, what flavour of Linux is your VM?

sorry, I've edited my post, using OS Debian Bullseye 11

The first command in your script (sudo apt update) is failing because another instance of apt is running -- likely one spawned by the VM's native bootstrapping process -- and holding apt's internal lock file:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 700 (apt-get)

Try adding this at the top of your script to wait for the other apt to finish:
#!/bin/sh

timeout=600 # (10 minute timeout)
i=0
while sudo fuser /var/lib/apt/lists/lock > /dev/null 2>&1; do
   sleep 1
   (( i+=1 ))
   if [[ $i == $timeout ]]; then
     exit 1 # Exit with error if timeout value is reached
   fi
done

The while loop polls the lock file until it is no longer being held open by the other apt, sleeping for 1 second between attempts.  If the timeout value is reached, the script exits with error.

it worked, I'm using #!/bin/bash, probably doesn't matter

The issue seems to be with installing gnupg. This is most likely because the repositories which the APT package sources burned in to image point to don't have gnupg1. You should try:

In your script line sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg software-properties-common, change gnupg to gnupg2.

Add the bullseye main repository to APT sources. Add the following lines to the top of your script:


# Add Debian APT package source
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

# Update sources
sudo apt update

Step 2 should only be requires if step 1 doesn't work on its own.

tried both steps, the cloud-init-output.log is the same "Could not get lock..."
